# Google drive api search for files using "or" to join clauses

Tags: search, google-drive-api

In looking at the `Search for files` Google drive api documentation I see there are `and` and `not` operators to join search clauses.

What is the best way to do an `or`?

For example I would like to search for all starred files or files that contain a given word.

I have written the following query:

```
(starred = true or title contains 'some text') and trashed = false
```

It seems to run but very very slowly. Is this the right way to do it or is there perhaps a better way to send multiple queries.

Worst case I could to 2 separate queries (but these would seem less efficient and require a dedupe step).

Comment: Sending two queryies is going to go against your quota its better to stick to just one query.